# How do I add more conference chair administrators in EasyChair?

Tags: easychair

I am the "first chair" of a conference, and I would like to add another chair in order to handle other administration areas like upgrading our license.  **How do I add another chair?**  It does not seem to be as easy as adding another CFP manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I figured it out!**  I was not able to find this specific how to in the [Help](https://easychair.org/help/) page, but it gave me a clue on where to explore. Here are the steps:

1. Log into EasyChair
2. Invite the potential new chair(s) to be on the
   Program Committee.
3. They will need to accept the invitation.
4. After acceptance, enter EasyChair in your chair role. Hover over the PC tab in the menu.
5. Click on "view PC" in the dropdown.
6. In the list of PC members, find the individual you would like to make a chair, and click on the update icon.
7. This will take you to the "Change Information About a PC Member" page.
8. There you will see in the "Kind" category two options.  Choose the option marked "chair".
9. Now click the red "Update Information" button.
10. All done.

The new chair should now be able to enter EasyChair using their chair role. For more information, see ["Adding a new program committee member"](https://easychair.org/help/adding_a_new_pc_member_or_chair?a=) in the My EasyChair [Help](https://easychair.org/help/) page.

Answer (score 0):

> > Greetings,
> >
> > I am the "first chair" of a conference, and I would like to add another chair in order to handle other administration areas like
> >     upgrading our license. How do I add another chair? It does not seem to
> >     be as easy as adding another CFP manager. How do I add more conference
> >     chair administrators in EasyChair?
> >
> > Kind regards,
>
> ---
>
> Dear Costumer,
>
> We received an email from you sent through the EasyChair contact page.
>   Your email seems to be a request for help in connection with an
>   existing EasyChair conference. For example, any question of the
>   following kinds:
>
> (1) How to do something in EasyChair
>     (2) How to submit to a conference
>     (3) Log in or account creation problems
>
> is automatically regarded as a helpdesk question. You should either
>   send helpdesk emails directly to the conference organizers or submit
>   them through our Helpdesk, if the conference has a license including
>   Helpdesk.
>
> If your conference has such a license, you will see the menu tab
>   "Premium" and its subitem "Help questions" when you log in to the
>   conference. In this case, you should post your question by following
>   these menu items.
>
> If your conference does not have these menu items in the interface,
>   its license does not include Helpdesk. To upgrade an EasyChair
>   license, one of the conference chairs should apply for a new license
>   by following menu items ->License management.
>
> Best regards, EasyChair

Answer (score 0):

One can go to https://easychair.org/conferences/pc_add.cgi?a=27949149 and select "superchair":

[image]

->

[image]